# Vista window appears at the top and cannot be deleted

Tags: windows-vista

I have no idea how he did it but on my dad's Vista laptop,  there is a window at the top; you can only drag it down but not remove, minimize or maximize it as those options do not appear. I restarted but it's still there.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: strange window]

How do I remove it? It used to be my laptop but I've never seen that when I used it.

Comment: Umm, you appear to have already asked this and accepted an answer on Stack Overflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765480/vista-window-appears-at-the-top-and-cannot-be-deleted

Comment: I thanked that user for forwarding me here. so It wouldn't appear in the unanswered questions. but that didn't fix my problem

Comment: Ah, so you did, apologies. Glad you fixed it in the end!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grey bar at the top is a user-created toolbar.

On the left end, there is a dotted vertical line.
Right-click the line and select "Close toolbar".

Comment: thanks :) I right clicked everywhere except there xD lol